# What's the difference between "turn out" and "end up"?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know when I must to use "turn out" and "end up". I notice that the "end up" is more universal than "turn out".

See an exemple:

I’m sure it will all **turn out** well in the end.

or

I’m sure it will all **end up** OK in the end.

Comment: From purely my own hearing of the words and personal usage of them I would say that 'turn out' is usually descriptive of a positive outcome whilst 'end up' is usually used of a negative result. It would be difficult to document or prove this. (And somewhat time-consuming.)